# How does a group action on a space induce action on cohomology ring of the space?

Tags: algebraic-topology

This is mostly a question to make sure I have some signs correct.  Let a group $G$ act on a space $X$.  As notation, for $g \in G$ let $\phi_g : X \rightarrow X$ be the map induced by the action of $g$.  It is then clear that we get an action on the homology of $X$ as follows:
$$g \cdot \vec{v} = (\phi_g)_{\ast}(\vec{v}) \quad \quad (g \in G, \vec{v} \in H_{\ast}(X)).$$
Here $(\phi_g)_{\ast} : H_{\ast}(X) \rightarrow H_{\ast}(X)$ is the induced map.

In the situation I'm in, I want an action on the cohomology of the space.  The problem then is that the naive recipe
$$g \cdot \vec{v} = (\phi_g)^{\ast}(\vec{v}) \quad \quad (g \in G, \vec{v} \in H^{\ast}(X))$$
does not yield and action since we have
$$(\phi_{g g'})^{\ast} = (\phi_{g'})^{\ast} (\phi_g)^{\ast}.$$
My guess is that the right thing to do would be to use
$$g \cdot \vec{v} = (\phi_{g^{-1}})^{\ast}(\vec{v}) \quad \quad (g \in G, \vec{v} \in H^{\ast}(X)).$$
Am I right that this is the reasonable thing to do?  Thanks!

Comment: This is a standard trick for turning a left action into a right action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.

To convince yourself that this is the right thing to do, you can use the example of how a group acts on a representation $V$ and its linear dual (one has to use inverse as you did). The standard way to calculate cohomology of a space at the level of chains is to take the simplicial chain complex of the space and dualize it.